# How would you solve for x, this line length inside a circle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

This is as far as my poor geometry skills have got me. I'm having people sit around a table and want them spaced at least one metre apart when from different households. X represents the distance between two people from different households. The line a represents the distance between two people from the same household.

This isn't an exam question. I'm setting up wedding tables and need people spaced a metre apart.

The tables we have are 6 feet so r=3, and a I would guess to be 2.

Comment: Can you add more information of the context like where did you encountered this question or what more do you know about the mathematical terms you used. It will be helpful for other users also to directly address the problem.

Comment: By the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem) the angle between $x$ and $a$ is also $120^\circ$. If you know $r$ and $a$, then you can solve for $x$ (e.g., law of cosines).

Comment: The vertex between $a$ and $x$ can lie anywhere in that arc. This results is infinite possible solutions for the two values.

Comment: a is a known value so should be solvable

Comment: @WillacyMe Do you know the number of persons, do you know how many households and how many persons from each of them are invited, the number of tables .... 
Example:  If we consider the diameter r=1m, ten you can have 6 persons from different hhs at the table, evenly spaced (vertices of a regular hexagon).

Comment: It's 6 to a table, 3 households, 2 from each household. I have 6 foot tables but want to see if 5 foot could do the job, depending how closely each couple from a household are spaced apart

Comment: At a table of 6 foot diameter you could seat 3 families of 4 members, each family separated by 3 foot from other and each family member about a foot from other family members. It seems you could easily use 5 foot tables. You need exact calculation or can do drawing now on your own?

Comment: I know this is likely the case but I'm interested in the maths behind working this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal diameter of the table to seat 3 pairs is calculated - It is 4.16 foot.

[image]

I assume that this answers your question.

Comment: This is perfect thank you! I knew there had to be a way.

Comment: Will than you accept the answer?

Comment: Apologies thought I had 